# Is there a constant-overhead PRP construction based on PRPs for large inputs?

Tags: pseudo-random-permutation

Somewhat recently I learned that there's a separation between an encryption scheme being CCA2 secure and being AE secure, namely PRPs.

So if we would use AES as an encryption scheme for fixed-size messages it would be CCA2 secure but not AE secure as an adversary can simply query any ciphertext and not get $\perp$ back but some random value instead distinguishing the decryption oracle from the always-$\perp$-oracle.

Now I know of two constructions that given a PRP $P:\{0,1\}^k\times\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$ construct a larger domain PRP:

- The Feistel construction yielding a PRP $F_P:\{0,1\}^k\times\{0,1\}^{2n}\to\{0,1\}^{2n}$
- The [EME construction](https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/147) yielding a PRP $E_P:\{0,1\}^k\times\{0,1\}^{mn}\to\{0,1\}^{mn}$ for $1\leq m\leq n$.

Using clever stacking of each individual of the two above constructions one can reach a scheme that is CCA2 secure but not AE secure for arbitrary input sizes. But there's a catch: The Feistel construction requires on average ~1/3 of the message size as additional padding as its permutation size only grows exponentially and EME also needs a non-constant (logarithmic?) amount of padding .

My question is now:
**Is there a known construction that takes a (s)PRP and constructs a larger-domain (s)PRP such that both large inputs (several GB) are supported and the overhead / required padding for the construction is bounded by a constant independent of the message size?**

---

Note: This is not intended for any practical application.

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe FPE can actually do this...

Comment: SIV modes? Hash the full plaintext and use as an input to the encryption. Also see all or nothing transforms.

Comment: @Natanael Actually it would appear there's no need for (keyless) hashing here as with PRPs we already have a key and can thus use a PRF (like CMAC). But yeah, I didn't think of SIV modes being PRPs (w/o tag checking) but it does make sense. Would you mind expanding your comment into an answer, so I can properly upvote / accept?

Comment: too lazy to write out a proper formal answer